# Elasticsearch, creating a Marvel monitoring cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-marvel

I'm reading the [installation documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/installing-marvel.html) for Marvel and this grabbed my attention:

> Configure Kibana to connect to your monitoring cluster by setting the
>   elasticsearch_url property in the kibana.yml configuration file. For
>   example:
>
> elasticsearch_url: "http://es-mon-1:9200"

Now this works well if I only want to install Marvel on Kibana and have the marvel indices stored on a different cluster. But what if I want to have my own Kibana dashboard as well to visualize my work cluster? How can I tell Kibana to use two different clusters?

Comment: You might add the version for elasticsearch and kibana, to improve possible answers, although it narrows down the possibilities. Since you are talking of Marvel, I assume you are still on the 2.x branch of Elasticsearch, right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right you want to see in the Kibana interface the data of different clusters? Therefore elasticsearch created the tribe node. See https://www.elastic.co/blog/tribe-node by the inventor Shay Banon himself.

---

Just an update, https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-stack-5-2-0-released?blade=tw The tribe node is also usable in Elasticsearch 5.2.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct. But to clarify. I need to have marvel store and read its indices on a monitoring cluster and have my own dashboards in Kibana to visualize my data cluster.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what a tribe node is for. You have your cluster for the monitoring data and your regular cluster for e.g. logging data. Elasticsearch added since v2.3.0 the tribe nodes, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/release-notes.html#_2_3_0. A tribe node connects both clusters, so they can see each other. Each cluster can query data from the other.